# Xen error "No usable disk have been found"

Tags: linux, virtualbox, xen, virt-manager

I have install following `Xen4` version on CentOS6.x but when i create VM and install OS it am getting following error before disk partition wizard `No usable disk have been found`

I used following CMD:

`virt-install -n vm01 -f /var/lib/xen/images/vm01.img -r 1024 --vcpus=1 -l http://10.0.0.1/centos --bridge=xenbr1`

I have tried using `dd` command to create disk too but still saying disk not found what that means?

also i tired `virt-manager` to create VM but no luck.

[image]

xm info

```
[root@localhost xen]# xm info
host                   : localhost
release                : 3.10.56-11.el6.centos.alt.x86_64
version                : #1 SMP Thu Oct 9 14:57:01 CDT 2014
machine                : x86_64
nr_cpus                : 2
nr_nodes               : 1
cores_per_socket       : 1
threads_per_core       : 2
cpu_mhz                : 3000
hw_caps                : bfebfbff:20100800:00000000:00000180:0000641d:00000000:00000000:00000000
virt_caps              : 
total_memory           : 8190
free_memory            : 6047
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 2
xen_extra              : .5-37.el6
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p 
xen_scheduler          : credit
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xffff800000000000
xen_changeset          : unavailable
xen_commandline        : dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all
cc_compiler            : gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
cc_compile_by          : mockbuild
cc_compile_domain      : centos.org
cc_compile_date        : Mon Oct 20 08:33:55 CDT 2014
xend_config_format     : 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You have to create `VM` disk on `LVM`

Create LVM disk

```
vcreate -L 8G -n XenVolVM01 XenVolGroup
```

Create VM

```
virt-install -p --name=vm01 --bridge=xenbr0 --file=/dev/mapper/XenVolGroup-XenVolVM01 --vcpus=2 --ram=2048 --graphics=none --location=http://10.0.0.1/centos6
```

## Booooom!!!

Comment: Or use `losetup` to use your image-file as device.